# Piggybank function to get maximum count of a count in each group

Tags: database, hadoop, apache-pig

I have data of the format

```
{group: chararray,finalItemsets: {(trans::sale::productId: int,product::serveRegion: chararray)}};
```

I want the product having maximum count in each group i.e. I am trying to get the productId in

```
{(trans::sale::productId: int,product::serveRegion: chararray)}
```

repeated maximum number of times and in each group.

Final output structure might look like this - `group, productId, maxCount(productId)`. So, is there any UDF in piggybank that let me do that.

Hoping to hear from you soon!.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input data?

Comment: ('south America': {(1021),(1022),(1022),(1022)}),( Mountain States,{(1021),(1077),(1021),(2866)}) and I am expecting something like this ( Mountain States, 1021, 2),(South America, 1022, 3)

Comment: possible duplicate of [apache Pig trying to get max count in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294411/apache-pig-trying-to-get-max-count-in-each-group)