# apache Pig trying to get max count in each group

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming

I have data of format in pig

`{(group, productId, count)}`.

Now I want to get maximum count in each group and the output might look as follows

`{(group, productId, maxCount)}`. Here is the sample input data

- `(south America,prod1, 45),(south America,prod2, 36), (latin america, prod1, 48),(latin america, prod5,35)`

here is the output for this input look like

1. `(south america, prod1, 45)`
2. `(North America, prod2, 36)`
3. `(latin america, prod1, 48)`

can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your sample input data, this should do the trick:

```
data = load 'sf.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (country:chararray, product:chararray, c:int);
g = group data by country;
result = foreach g {
    prods = order data by c desc;
    top_prods = limit prods 1;
    generate flatten(top_prods);
}
dump result;
```

This groups the input by first column, then in the nested foreach it orders the products per group by count, then takes the first (highest count).

Output:

```
(latin america,prod1,48)
(south America,prod1,45)
```